# How to use laravel relations to get data from database

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am wokring on a home page in which I have to show the Feature Category Supplier slider.
Hear is what I want:

I want to get the random 3 Featured categories form category table and of that each category have 6 suppliers which i also want to display.

Database Structure:

#### Category Table contain the `is_featured` Flag.

```
id  | is_featured

1   |   1
2   |   1
3   |   1
4   |   1
... so on
```

I have supplier categories table in which i have mapped the supplier and there categories.

#### SupplierCategoryMappingTable

```
id  | sup_id | cat_id
1   |   1    |  1
2   |   2    |  2
3   |   3    |  3
4   |   4    |  4
5   |   5    |  5
...so on
```

And Supplier table in which i have supplier details.

#### Supplier Table

```
id  | sup_name ....Other details
1   | ABC
2   | DEF
3   | HIJ
4   | LLK
5   | OPQ
6   | SDE
...so on
```

### What i have tried so far.

I have trid to give `hasMany` Relation but get empty item array.I am thinking that category has many supplier so i have added has many.

```
public function supplierList() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\DB\Supplier\SupplierCategoryDetail', 'cat_id', 'id');        
}
```

Some how i have figur it out to get random category. but after using `with()` it gives empty result.

```
$data['featured_category'] = Category::with('supplierList')->where('status','1')->inRandomOrder()->limit(3)->get();`
```

I am completely new in laravel and it's relations. I am doing this using eloquent in laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you make use of a pivot a "many to many" relation is possible. In this case you want to use `belongsToMany`.

Your relation would look like:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(
    'App\DB\Supplier\SupplierCategoryDetail',
    'SupplierCategoryMappingTable', // or what the name is of the table
    'cat_id',
    'sup_id'
);
```

Also I do not see the `status` column in your category table. It looks like this should be `is_featured`.

Without testing I think you final query could look like:

```
Category::with('supplierList')
    ->where('is_featured', '1')
    ->inRandomOrder()
    ->limit(3)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this documentation: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

You should write relationship functions on both the models which are related to each other.

Please do this:

*Category.php*

```
public function supplierCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SupplierCategory');
    }
```

*Supplier.php*

```
public function supplierCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SupplierCategory');
    }
```

*SupplierCategory.php*

```
public function supplier()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Supplier');
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
```

*Controller.php*

```
$results = SupplierCategory::inRandomOrder()->limit(3)->get();

      return view('index', compact('results'));
```

*index.blade.php*

```
@foreach($results as $result)
         {{$result->supplier}}
         {{$result->category}}
      @endforeach
```